# Are adjacent fields in techum shabbat or not?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, techum

BSD

In Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Chapter 95:1

> "  והיינו אם היה בין השמשות בשדה אבל אם שבת בתוך עיר כל העיר הוא מקומו. ועיבורה      של עיר נחשב ג"כ להעיר"

Sorry if this is a beginners question but my understanding of this halacha is that if one is outside the city in a field during Bein Hashmashot but will arrive in the city on Shabbat then the city is part of his "place."

Question:
Does being in the field here mean that he was within 2,000 amot of the city or outside of it? 
Because if

a) He was in the city limits (2,000 amot) I am confused because its already been said in the [beginning of the halacha](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur95.html) that one is allowed to walk within 2000 amot of the city already. Wouldnt that already apply to Bein Hashmashot as well?

or if...

b) He was outside the city limits. Wouldnt it be assur at Shkiah to go 4 amot. So then how would he arrive to the city on Shabbat if he can only walk approx 6 feet?

This seems like too simple of a question so I may be missing something, sorry if this is too novice of a question.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering, i'm going to quote [the entire se'if](http://www.kitzur.net/main.php?siman=95) for a bit of context:

> אסור לצאת בשבת וביום-טוב ממקום ששבת, יותר מתחום, שהוא שני אלפים אמה. ומקומו של אדם הוא ארבע אמות. והינו אם היה בין השמשות בשדה. אבל אם שבת בתוך העיר, כל העיר היא מקומו. ועבורה של עיר, נחשב גם כן לעיר. ואיזה הוא עבורה. שבעים אמה ושני שלישי אמה, ושיך לעיר אע"פ שאין שם בנין, והוא הנקרא קרפף העיר. וממקום שיכלה, מתחילין למדד תחום שבת

Now, what exactly is it talking about?

The first sentence says that you cannot go more than tchum (2000 amot) outside of your מקום שביתה - place of rest.

What is your מקום שביתה?

In a field (the first part that you quoted) - it is 4 amot.
However, if his מקום שביתה is in a city - all the city (and its extension of 70.6 amot) is considered part of his מקום שביתה.

This seems to be where the misunderstanding came about. "אם שבת בתוך עיר" does not mean "if he will arrive in the city on Shabbat". Rather, "if he rested in the city". "שבת" here is a verb.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: If a person is קונה שביתה (acquires his "place" INSIDE the city then he has permission to walk the entire city plus its Ibur (extention of 70+ Amos) plus 2000 Amos in eithr direction.

If, however, if he was קונה שביתה OUTSIDE of the city he only has 2000 Amois from his 4 Amos.

To address the last question: the 4 Amos "space" only means where he was קונה שביתה it does not mean that he could only walk within those 4 Amos.

Comment: source?........